# Можно ли как то сократить процесс заполнения кнопок?

Tags: массивы, wpf, циклы, wpf-grid

Можно ли как то сократить процесс заполнения кнопок? А именно сделать как то это в цикле. Суть была в том чтобы создать поле с помощью грида, но вот сам процесс его заполнения мне кажется слишком громоздким...

```
    pole = new int[8, 8]
        {
            {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2},
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11},
            {12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 14, 13, 12},
        };


        button0_1.Content=1.ToString();
        button1_1.Content=1.ToString();
        button2_1.Content=1.ToString();
        button3_1.Content=1.ToString();
        button4_1.Content=1.ToString();
        button5_1.Content=1.ToString();
        button6_1.Content=1.ToString();
        button7_1.Content=1.ToString();
        button0_0.Content=2.ToString();
        button1_0.Content=3.ToString();
        button2_0.Content=4.ToString();
        button3_0.Content=5.ToString();
        button4_0.Content=6.ToString();
        button5_0.Content=4.ToString();
        button6_0.Content=3.ToString();
        button7_0.Content=2.ToString();
        button0_1.Tag=1;
        button1_1.Tag=1;
        button2_1.Tag=1;
        button3_1.Tag=1;
        button4_1.Tag=1;
        button5_1.Tag=1;
        button6_1.Tag=1;
        button7_1.Tag=1;
        button0_0.Tag=2;
        button1_0.Tag=3;
        button2_0.Tag=4;
        button3_0.Tag=5;
        button4_0.Tag=6;
        button5_0.Tag=4;
        button6_0.Tag=3;
        button7_0.Tag=2;


        button0_6.Content=11.ToString();
        button1_6.Content=11.ToString();
        button2_6.Content=11.ToString();
        button3_6.Content=11.ToString();
        button4_6.Content=11.ToString();
        button5_6.Content=11.ToString();
        button6_6.Content=11.ToString();
        button7_6.Content=11.ToString();
        button0_7.Content=12.ToString();
        button1_7.Content=13.ToString();
        button2_7.Content=14.ToString();
        button3_7.Content=15.ToString();
        button4_7.Content=16.ToString();
        button5_7.Content=14.ToString();
        button6_7.Content=13.ToString();
        button7_7.Content=12.ToString();

        button0_6.Tag=11;
        button1_6.Tag=11;
        button2_6.Tag=11;
        button3_6.Tag=11;
        button4_6.Tag=11;
        button5_6.Tag=11;
        button6_6.Tag=11;
        button7_6.Tag=11;
        button0_7.Tag=12;
        button1_7.Tag=13;
        button2_7.Tag=14;
        button3_7.Tag=15;
        button4_7.Tag=16;
        button5_7.Tag=14;
        button6_7.Tag=13;
        button7_7.Tag=12;



        button0_5.Content="";
        button1_5.Content="";
        button2_5.Content="";
        button3_5.Content="";
        button4_5.Content="";
        button5_5.Content="";
        button6_5.Content="";
        button7_5.Content="";
        button0_4.Content="";
        button1_4.Content="";
        button2_4.Content="";
        button3_4.Content="";
        button4_4.Content="";
        button5_4.Content="";
        button6_4.Content="";
        button7_4.Content="";
        button0_3.Content="";
        button1_3.Content="";
        button2_3.Content="";
        button3_3.Content="";
        button4_3.Content="";
        button5_3.Content="";
        button6_3.Content="";
        button7_3.Content="";
        button0_2.Content="";
        button1_2.Content="";
        button2_2.Content="";
        button3_2.Content="";
        button4_2.Content="";
        button5_2.Content="";
        button6_2.Content="";
        button7_2.Content="";
        button0_5.Tag=0;
        button1_5.Tag=0;
        button2_5.Tag=0;
        button3_5.Tag=0;
        button4_5.Tag=0;
        button5_5.Tag=0;
        button6_5.Tag=0;
        button7_5.Tag=0;
        button0_4.Tag=0;
        button1_4.Tag=0;
        button2_4.Tag=0;
        button3_4.Tag=0;
        button4_4.Tag=0;
        button5_4.Tag=0;
        button6_4.Tag=0;
        button7_4.Tag=0;
        button0_3.Tag=0;
        button1_3.Tag=0;
        button2_3.Tag=0;
        button3_3.Tag=0;
        button4_3.Tag=0;
        button5_3.Tag=0;
        button6_3.Tag=0;
        button7_3.Tag=0;
        button0_2.Tag=0;
        button1_2.Tag=0;
        button2_2.Tag=0;
        button3_2.Tag=0;
        button4_2.Tag=0;
        button5_2.Tag=0;
        button6_2.Tag=0;
        button7_2.Tag=0;
```

Comment: Я не понимаю, что это за язык программирования. Но нужно использовать циклы, ты даже сам об этом сказал. На каком языке ты пишешь?

Comment: c# с графическим интерфейсом WPF

Comment: Тогда ничего тяжелого, тут есть вся [информация](http://c-sharp.pro/?p=651)

Comment: Я это читал уже, но как это перенести на заполнение кнопок в цикле?